# How is a complete image of a distant object formed with an obstruction in the line of sight?

Tags: optics, astronomy, geometric-optics

Can anyone please link to or sketch a diagram demonstrating how a complete (and clear) image can be formed of a distant celestial object with a central obstruction blocking part of the line of sight in a reflector telescope?

A written explanation would also be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do you need at least two rays to form an image?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/233603/why-do-you-need-at-least-two-rays-to-form-an-image) with the obsticle at the centre rather than at the edges.